# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR , propagateSizeHints() errors

Tags: python, environment-variables, qt5, xcb, music21

When I run this script "python3 script.py" everything is alright.
(I tried to run the script as a root, and other user too)

```
import music21
import os

# "qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display"
# "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found." 
os.putenv("QT_QPA_PLATFORM", "offscreen") #handle error above in my case

us = music21.environment.UserSettings()
us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = '/usr/bin/musescore3'

score = music21.converter.parse("myfile.musicxml")
score.write('musicxml.pdf', fp='song.pdf')
```

But when my django backend has to execute this code as a function to respond API call, its not working. I got:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-myusername'
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
```

And if I remove part with "QT_QPA_PLATFORM", I got "qt.qpa.xcb" error.
I have not idea what to do.
I also tried to add following line in my gunicorn setup script but nothing changed.

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

Any ideas how to fix it ? What can be wrong ?

Server OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to also set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. See https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/260#issuecomment-834489173